# The animation only works with the first click of the button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to create simple text animation. When i click a button, text shifts from fully transparent to fully visible and reverts to transparent. I wrote code that does the animation but only once. The animation doesn't work anymore every time when i click the button:

```js
function animation() {
  $("span").removeClass("opacity-effect");
  $("span").addClass("opacity-effect");
}
```

```css
span{
  opacity: 0;
}

.opacity-effect {
  animation-name: animate-opacity-effect;
  animation-duration: 1400ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;

}

@keyframes animate-opacity-effect {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Hello World!</span>
<button onClick="animation()">
   Start animation
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation does not repeat, because for animation to start CSS requires a frame when there was no class.

So, to solve this, you should delay adding class to the next frame

```js
function animation() {
  $("span").removeClass("opacity-effect");
  requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
    $("span").addClass("opacity-effect");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to **reset** the animation. There is a good and correct way to do this, using event `animationend`. In this event, you need to put the removal of the class `opacity-effect`.

```js
function animation() {
    $("span").addClass("opacity-effect");
    $("span").on("animationend", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("opacity-effect");
    });
}
```

```css
span {
    opacity: 0;
}

.opacity-effect {
    animation-name: animate-opacity-effect;
    animation-duration: 1400ms;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes animate-opacity-effect {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Hello World!</span>
<button onClick="animation()">
    Start animation
</button>
```

Comment: I didn't really mean it. My point is for this animation to play every time you press the button (but only once)

Comment: @AdamWróbel, I updated the solution and made it with event `animationend`. This event is for tasks like this task. Check it.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Dropdown value from database</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    span{
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .opacity-effect {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-animation: animate-opacity-effect 1400ms infinite;
        -moz-animation: animate-opacity-effect 1400ms infinite;
        -o-animation: animate-opacity-effect 1400ms infinite;
            animation: animate-opacity-effect 1400ms infinite;
    }

    @keyframes animate-opacity-effect  {
        0%   { opacity:1; }
        50%  { opacity:0; }
        100% { opacity:1; }
    }
    @-o-keyframes animate-opacity-effect {
        0%   { opacity:1; }
        50%  { opacity:0; }
        100% { opacity:1; }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes animate-opacity-effect {
        0%   { opacity:1; }
        50%  { opacity:0; }
        100% { opacity:1; }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes animate-opacity-effect {
        0%   { opacity:1; }
        50%  { opacity:0; }
        100% { opacity:1; }
    }


  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span>Hello World!</span>
    <button onClick="animation()">
       Start animation
    </button>

<script>
function animation() {
  $("span").removeClass("opacity-effect");
  $("span").addClass("opacity-effect");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"complete source code"* that does what?  At least make it a snippet so we can see it in action.  Please see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a small delay between the `removeClass` and the `addClass`. This can be done in two ways:

**With a setTimeout**

```js
function animation() {
  $("span").removeClass("opacity-effect")
  setTimeout(() => {
    $("span").addClass("opacity-effect");
  }, 0);
}
```

```css
span{
  opacity: 0;
}

.opacity-effect {
  animation-name: animate-opacity-effect;
  animation-duration: 1400ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animate-opacity-effect {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Hello World!</span>
<button onClick="animation()">
   Start animation
</button>
```

**With a cloning**

```js
function animation() {
  const newEl = $("span").removeClass("opacity-effect").clone(true);
  $("span").before(newEl);
  $("span:last").remove();
  newEl.addClass("opacity-effect");
}
```

```css
span{
  opacity: 0;
}

.opacity-effect {
  animation-name: animate-opacity-effect;
  animation-duration: 1400ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animate-opacity-effect {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Hello World!</span>
<button onClick="animation()">
   Start animation
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('span').addClass('opacity-effect');
setTimeout(function(){
 $('span').removeClass('opacity-effect');
}, 1400);
```

Try this
**1400 is your animation duration time**